# Req.params of EJS doesn't work with Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, parameters, ejs

I'm here because I create an express app and with

```
app.get('/admin/edit/articles/:id', function(req, res) {
var Article = require(__dirname + '/models/article.js');

if(req.params.id != null || req.params.id != '') {
  Article.findById(req.param('id'), function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
  res.render('admin/articles/edit', {id: req.params.id, title: result.local.title, content: result.local.content});
}
});
```

When I go to /admin/edit/articles/234 it return

> Cannot GET /admin/edit/articles/234

I use **EJS(~0.8.5)**, **Express(~4.0.0)** and **Mongoose(~3.8.1)**.

I look forward to reading your answers

Comment: You need to put the `res.render` call inside the `findById` callback.

Comment: Post everything you are doing with `app` above the app.get line. Also, what is the response code? 404?

Comment: Are you sure your express server is actually running?  Does a `console.log()` statement inside of the `app.get()` callback get output?

Comment: Also, try `req.params['id']`, and add an `} else {` block that sends `res.status(404).send()`, because the request will hang if the condition is not met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mea culpa, I forgot a 's' in the url.

Thanks for everything.